# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play some videos

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

The code below can play videos on my server but not playing from Mail.ru or some remote servers.

I get the video url from official Mail.ru API, everything is fine with url but MPMoviePlayerController is not playing.

```
 NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn36.video.mail.ru/hv/44216657.mp4?sign=e64028dd09fb5970a79c4b092ade56d293437187&slave[]=c%3Acdn28.video.mail.ru&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F44216657-hv.mp4&p=0&expire_at=1390334400&touch=1381076396"];
    theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];
    theMoviPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    theMoviPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350);
    theMoviPlayer.movieSourceType= MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
    [theMoviPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    [self.view addSubview:theMoviPlayer.view];

    [self.theMoviPlayer play];
```

Comment: the link points to a page that says forbidden